# Database Scheme for unified profiles fetched from multiple Social Networks (Facebook and Linkedin...)

Tags: mongodb, database-design, social-networking

The [application](http://beeplapp.com/) I'm building allows users to login using both their Facebook and Linkedin Accounts in order to fetch their friend from these networks.
Each of their friend can be a user of the application.

I have a couple of problems to solve:

1. How should I structure my Database Schema?
2. How do I unify profiles?

### Potential Solutions

#### Regarding the structure:

I'm using mongo (But am open to suggestions). So I though that i'd create a `collection` of `Users` where each user document looks like this:

`User = {
  appId: <id>,
  connections: [userId]
}`

So, each user has:

1. A unique app generated id (could be the doc's id for simplicity).
2. An array of user's IDs. The IDs of their Friend's profiles created in my app.

#### Regarding Unifying profiles:

Should I unify users based on their email or name? or both?

### Misc

I though that I could use [LoginRadius](https://www.loginradius.com/) but i was using [singly](http://singly.com/) just for that, and then they suddenly decided to kill the service. In other words, I don't want to depend on a third party tool because this is a core feature.

Comment: Unify users based on email of course :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
                 name: { type: String, default: '' },
                 email: { type: String, default: '' },
                 provider: { type: String, default: '' },
                 hashed_password: { type: String, default: '' },
                 salt: { type: String, default: '' },
                 authToken: { type: String, default: '' },
                 facebook: {},
                 linkedin: {}
     })
```

I'm using the Schema mentioned above for my users collection.

and when a new user wants to Sign up, using either the local strategy or social strategies

I just use the update mongoose function with the "upsert: true"  option, to either update or

create an entry.